# Login is changed by other users if 2 or more users click on same page at same time

Tags: asp.net

In my application when two or more users logged in and if they click on same page at same time(at exact time) then one's login is changed by others login .
The code on my page load event is as followes.

```
MembershipUser mUser = Membership.GetUser();

if (mUser != null)
{
    aspUserId.Value = mUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AspNetUserID", mUser.ProviderUserKey);
    string sPMSUserId = dbHandler.GetSingleValue(cmd, "get_PMSUserId");
    hdnUserID.Value = sPMSUserId;


}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");
}
```

hdnUserID is used to pass value to sqlDatasource select statement parameter.
 aspUserId is also i used to test aspnet_UserID of user. I test it by using inspect element
 .I found that it's value is changed by other user's aspnet_UserID.

in DBHandler i used connection string as like

```
string strconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strconn"].ConnectionString;
```

with code like that

```
 public string GetSingleValue(SqlCommand sqlcmdWithParameters, string CommandText) 
{ 
    string sReturn = ""; 
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strconn); 
    sqlcmdWithParameters.Connection = sqlcon; 
    sqlcmdWithParameters.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    sqlcmdWithParameters.CommandText = CommandText; 
    try 
    { 
        sqlcon.Open(); 
        sReturn = Convert.ToString(sqlcmdWithParameters.ExecuteScalar()); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        sReturn = "-1"; 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        sqlcon.Close(); 
    } 
    return sReturn; 
}
```

Finally I  got cause of problem. Yeah it is due to Cache

on .aspx page i take directive of OutputCache as

```
       <%@ OutputCache Duration ="1" NoStore ="true" VaryByParam ="*" %>
```

this keeps my page to cache for 1 second. If another page make request within 1 seconds that page in cache is return even though it is of another user .

Comment: How exact is "exact time" anyway, It must be difficult getting two computers to post a login to a server at the *exact same time*?

Answer (score 1):

What does your `DBHandler` look like? Are you somehow sharing one connection for all database work (e.g. the connection is a static member of `DBHandler`)?

The code you've posted here is probably not the problem. It's more likely that you somewhere unintentionally share a resource between requests without proper locking.

Comment: @Sachin: You should not try to edit Anders answer, update your own question instead